# How to debug and roll back to recent software update in 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, software-center

I just updated system using software updater in Ubuntu 16.04. I also installed the NVM and NodeJS. I also uninstalled virtualenv by deleting some `/usr/lib/Python3/....` files.

I think the update caused the trouble. My system loads some files while booting. Starts some services and then just freezes. The ctrl+alt+F2 to change tty terminal doesn't work. Even while anything is booting.

I want to roll it back to the previous status. Where are the logs? How to roll back the "Software Updater" update [My guess apt doesn't apply here.].

The terminal mode (recovery mode) in the Advanced Options of Grub2 does work.

I don't know where to start. How to debug the updates? What is the software/tools to roll back the previous status?

I don't know if networking mode in Advanced Options of Grub2 is working or not.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu has roll back processing.

Comment: oh. It does not have roll back for a bad update? How sad. Not anticipated.

Comment: I have lot of stuff. I'm doomed! Thanks anyway

Comment: You should find the logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. You would have to downgrade all updated packages manually. Try to boot with an elder kernel from Grub's advanced options menu, just to check if it's just a kernel-upgrade which gives you the headache.

Comment: apt/history records "software updater"'s activities?